# How to generate logs from a winform in VS2013(c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am working on winforms in visual studio 2013 (c#) . I have a list box where all the events are logged.I need to get this log also stored separately in a notepad.How can I do that.
WHen I click a button,the message should be stored in the list box as well as a notepad separately.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
     if (button1.Text.Equals("DOOR OPEN"))  
        {  
            if (true == DescendingTime.Checked)  
          {  
            ListDataBox.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now + " Door Opened ...");  
                button1.Text = "DOOR CLOSE";  
                var path = "C:/Users/AP140563/Documents/Visual Studio2013/Projects/AMSimulator/AMSimulator/bin/Debug/log";    
               var message = "Door Opened ...";  
                System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[]{message});  

            }  
            else  
            {
                ListDataBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " Door Opened ...");
                button1.Text = "DOOR CLOSE";
            }
        }
        else if (button1.Text.Equals("DOOR CLOSE"))
        {
            if (true == DescendingTime.Checked)
            {
                ListDataBox.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now + " Door Closed ...");
                button1.Text = "DOOR OPEN";
            }
            else
            {
                ListDataBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " Door Closed ...");
                button1.Text = "DOOR OPEN";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What logging system are you using.  Please show the code.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Log method, instead of adding an item to ListBox do this:

```
var path = "Path to your log file";
var message = "Message to log"
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[]{message});
```

An example of path could be this:

```
var path= System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Log.txt");
```

Remember that is is just a sample of how you can append a line of text to a file and is not a logging system at all.

Comment: I tried ur method..am getting an error as path cannot be accesed

Comment: A logging system should be able to fail without affecting the application.

Comment: @TomBlodget you are right, but I am not creating a logging system here, it is just a simple answer for a user who wants to log in 'notepad' ;)

Comment: @ap87 Use "\" instead of "/" and use a file name at the end of path, for example @"C:\Users\AP140563\Documents\Visual Studio2013\Projects\AMSimulator\AMSimulator\bin\Debug\log.txt" and more important Its better to address your file relative to your application, I'll show it in answer

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks ...it worked... "Use "\" instead of "/"" this is giving an error.. so am using / this only...

Comment: @ap87 By the way, when you find an answer helpful, you can kindly accept it as answer and/or vote it up:), this way it will be more useful for other users in future.